# How do I count total distinct items in a one-to-many join query in Hibernate JPQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, db2, hql, jpql

I'm having trouble getting the total count of the "one" side of a one-to-many join query in hibernate HQL / JPQL.

The two tables I'm attempting to join (which I don't control and cannot change) look something like this:

```
House:
PK FK: owner_id
PK: town
PK: state
PK FK: inspection_id

Car:
PK FK: owner_id
PK: town
PK: state
PK: vin
```

An owner can own many houses and many cars, but a car can be garaged in only one home. So the relationship between house and car is one to many. And the query I'm attempting to run looks like this

```
entityManager.createQuery(
    "select count(distinct h) " + // also tried "select count(*)", but that counts cars per garage for some reason.
    "from House h, Car c " +
    "where h.owner.id = c.owner.id " +
    "and h.town = c.town " +
    "and h.state = c.state " +
    "and h.inspection_id between 1 and 10 " +
    "and c.vin between 12345 and 23456 " +
    "group by h, c",
Long.class).getSingleResult().intValue();
```

But I'm getting an error when I try to run this query against my DB2 database. Apparently the distinct keyword doesn't work in db2. But am I doing this correctly? Is there another way to accomplish this with JPQL?

Why do I get a list of each houses car count when I replace "distinct h" with "*"?

Any help would be appreciated. Here's the exception I'm seeing:

```
11:13:56,753 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (batchProcessPool-1) SQL Error: -170, SQLState: 42605
11:13:56,754 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (batchProcessPool-1) DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-170, SQLSTATE=42605, SQLERRMC=COUNT, DRIVER=4.18.60
11:13:56,754 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (batchProcessPool-1) SQL Error: -516, SQLState: 26501
11:13:56,754 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (batchProcessPool-1) DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-516, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=4.18.60
11:13:56,754 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (batchProcessPool-1) SQL Error: -514, SQLState: 26501
11:13:56,754 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (batchProcessPool-1) DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-514, SQLSTATE=26501, SQLERRMC=SQL_CURLN200C1, DRIVER=4.18.60
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
...
```

**EDIT**

Thanks to @bowmore's suggestion, I revised the query to use the exists() function and it seems to be working! Thanks!

```
entityManager.createQuery(
    "select count(h) " +
    "from House h " +
    "where h.inspection_id between 1 and 10 " +
    "and exists (" +
        "select c.vin from Car c " +
        "where c.town = h.town " +
        "and c.state = h.state " +
        "and c.owner.id = h.owner.id " +
        "and c.vin between 12345 and 23456)",
Long.class).getSingleResult().intValue();
```

Comment: My HQL is rusty as hell, but in plain SQL I'd make a query that looks like this : `select count(*) from House h where exists (select * from Car where ...) and h.inspection_id between 1 and 10`

Comment: For one, `count (distinct <expression>)` requires a scalar expression, while you're supplying a table references `h`.

Comment: @mustaccio ah, ok thanks, yah supplying h as the parameter was being evaluated to a list of the House table's primary keys in the hql, but I guess it's expecting a "scalar expression" meaning an expression that's evaluated into a single value rather than a list?

Comment: And @bowmore thank you! I hadn't thought about using the exists function, but I think that may work for me.